# Ошибка при подключении mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /home/u707093444/public_html/startup.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.2.1.45'
>   (using password: NO) in /home/u707093844/public_html/startup.php on
>   line 15 No connect with data base

что это значит? помогите исправить.

Comment: В тексте ошибки вполне понятно написано в чем дело и что надо делать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u707093444/public_html/startup.php on line 15

Слово *deprecated* означает «устарело».

> Устарело: mysql_connect(). Расширение (или дополнение, плагин) *mysql* устарело и в будущем будет удалено. Вместо него используйте mysqli или PDO. Ошибка в  /home/u707093444/public_html/startup.php на строке 15

---

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.2.1.45' (using password: NO) in /home/u707093844/public_html/startup.php on line 15 No connect with data base
>
> Предупреждение: mysql_connect(): Пользователю 'root'@'10.2.1.45' (с использованием пароля: НЕТ) запрещен доступ. Ошибка /home/u707093844/public_html/startup.php на строке 15: «Нет соединения с базой данных»

В общем, учите технический английский. Сообщения об ошибках вполне понятно сформулированы.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL &~ E_DEPRECATED);
```

чтобы убрать первую

и использовать правильный пароль, чтобы вторую.

но лучше всего вообще не использовать такой старый код, а найти что-нибудь поновее.